# Method called from codebehind with ajax return undefine

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, ajax

I want to get value from codebehind that then I call it using ajax, but I got nothing, in succes it just show undefine , here the code

```
function PopMensaje() {

            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "/WebForms/Modulo Tramites/ProcesosTramites/frmIniciarTramite.aspx/metodoajax",
                data: '{}',
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                dataType: "json",
                success: function (result) {
                    alert("retorno "+result.d);
                },
                error: function () {
                    alert('Ocurrio un error');

                }
            });
```

on calling show

```
    };
```

and this the function in codebehind

```
  [WebMethod]
  public static string metodoajax(){
        return "123";
    }
```

on calling shows "retorno undefine".I expect it shows  "retorno 123"

What I'm doing wrong? How to fix this?

Comment: What output does `console.log(result);` give you?

Comment: this is what it shows:                                                                               Object { Message: "Authentication failed.", StackTrace: null, ExceptionType: "System.InvalidOperationException" }

Comment: Well you are returning a string and you expect to read `d`???

Comment: Sounds like you have other problems, mainly to do with authentication. I reckon if you put a `System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Test")` before your `return 123;`, I doubt you will see that debug because its failing earlier on.

Comment: You are right @JosephGarrone it's not going into the method.

Comment: url: "/WebForms/Modulo Tramites/ProcesosTramites/frmIniciarTramite.aspx/metodoajax

.....Your url has a problem... you are using whitespaces in ModuloTramites.... change it... and see if it works... @Aaron

Comment: I tried with other url without whitespaces and get the same undefine message

Answer (score 0):

You function works fine. I think that your are missing jQuery in your webform and the closing brace for your javascript function:

```
        <head runat="server">
          <script src="Scripts/jquery-2.1.4.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
       </head>
```